# Samsung Galaxy S3 update installs strange applications

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, updates, device-firmware

Today I updated the software to latest version. It took around 148MB to update and when finished, I started getting 4 new apps:

- mytaxi
- kaufDA
- pizza.de
- BILD

Wondering why these apps were installed, because my friends' S3 didn't have this.

Please let me know, if this is not an original phone or why, as I understood this seems to be a German version. However, when I checked the IMEI, 7th and 8th digits are respectively 0 and 5, not 0 and 8 to be German.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those apps are stock apps in the German-localized ROMs for the Galaxy S3 (the i9300 version). Likely they were there in the original ROM but you uninstalled them and later forgot about it. It's fine to just uninstall them.

The seventh and eight digits of the IMEI don't have any meaning in current phones. Before 2004, they indicated the country where the phone was assembled, but the structure of the IMEI was changed then so those two digits don't have a special meaning of their own.

There's nothing here to suggest your phone is a fake.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have any idea why does galaxy s3 gets sluggish when returning from lock screen to home screen? its damn slow. appreciate your reply.

Comment: If you have a new question, use the **Ask question** button. Posting it in the comments below an answer is a good way to make sure people won't see it.